# The difference between "to think about" and "to think of"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between “think of” and “think about”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71003/difference-between-think-of-and-think-about)

What is the difference between "to think about" and "to think of", when we can mix them and when not? I often met them in any paper I read. My dictionary doesn't provide with details regarding this situation.

Thanks.

Comment: What does Chris think of it? It's probably a matter of depth here: When you *think of* something, you give it a cursory glance; when you *think about* something, you give it substantial thought.

Comment: @Kris: great explanation and very concise! (+1)

Comment: @JAM I don't agree with the accepted answer on the 71003. See my comment above -- what do you think *about* it? (*of* it?)

Comment: @Kris: for a profound analysis one must say "OK, I'll think about it" or simply "I think about it":-) Anyway, I got the point! Thanks!

Comment: @Kris: yeah, it would be nice to have it posted.

Comment: @Kris I don't disagree with the accepted answer on 71003; I think that it, the other answers, and your answer here, all provide different angles on the same deceptively simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with the accepted answer. You can "think of" something that is important and detailed.

> Newton thought of a way to explain the workings of the solar system.

That is no "cursory glance" at the topic, but the result of a sustained and reasoned effort to create a theory.

Similarly, to "think about" something may not mean to think in depth.

> Drunk and giddy with pleasure, we thought about our days together as children.

This may mean a series of random associations, not a substantial act of mental labor.

To my way of thinking, there are so many variations on the meanings of "to think of" and "to think about" that it is impossible to draw distinct lines between the two terms. Sometimes they are synonyms, sometimes they are something else. Take this example from Wallace Stevens' poem, "The Sense of the Sleight of Hand Man":

> To think of a dove with an eye of grenadine
>   And pines that are cornets, so it occurs,

This is both a trivial application of "think of" and a profound one. It is a fleeting passage of imagination but also a deep epiphany. It is much more than the same construction used in a sentence like "I'm thinking of a number between one and ten."

You can "think about" something deeply or shallowly. Usually it means to consider something, but occasionally it means something different. In the following sentence, it means cursory attention was given to a notion:

> I thought about saving some of the ice cream for my sister, but decided to be greedy and eat the rest instead.

Yet "think about" can be profound as well. In the screenplay to the film *Mystery, Alaska*, John (played by Russell Crowe) confronts Charles (Hank Azaria), the promoter of the big hockey game:

> You brought back the one thing that could tear the heart out of this place. Now, either you thought about that or you didn't.

This is a stunning, multi-layered accusation: If Charles had actually thought about the risk and proceeded in spite of it, he was someone who put personal success above the good of his hometown. But if he *hadn't* given it enough thought, he was either stupid and insensitive or the welfare of his hometown didn't matter much at all.

In summary, both expressions are capable of nuance and affected by context. There is no clear, cut-and-dried distinction to draw between them, no simple differentiator that will work in all cases.

Comment: thank you for your very detailed answer! (+1) It seems hard to define a strict rule that makes the difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a matter of depth here: When you *think of* something, you give it a cursory glance; when you *think about* something, you give it substantial thought.

Comment: "Newton thought of a way to explain the workings of the solar system." Does that sound like a cursory glance to you?

Comment: @Robusto: do you think it is more than that?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @Robusto: maybe it's hard to give here a complete answer that catches all possible situations.

Comment: @Chris'ssister: My point exactly. See my own answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

'To think about' something is to look for an answer or make a decision.
'To think of' something, is to create an idea in you mind, or recall to mind.

Comment: hmmm, this seems a bit different from the previous answer in terms of "to think of".

Comment: I didn't think of that! :) Sounds a bit far fetched, though.

Comment: @Kris: then maybe you should think about it. :-)

Comment: It's very unlikely -- which's why I said 'far fetched'.

Comment: @Brian Litton: (+1) for your efforts

Comment: I couldn't find the correct explanation for the next sentence "He told me his name, but I can't think of it now", but your "recall to mind" clarified everything. Many thanks.