# Difference between "Being Of" and "Being About"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, philosophy

I am trying to understand the difference between *Being of something* and *Being about something*.

I've been [reading about the difference](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71003/difference-between-think-of-and-think-about) between *Think of* and *Think about*, but I'm still not sure how it applies to Being ?

The complete sentence is :

> *In summary, any (object-directed) conscious experience, in addition to being of or about its intentional object is pre-reflectively
>   manifest to itself.*

It comes from a very good introductory [text related to phenomenology](https://cfs.ku.dk/staff/zahavi-publications/phenomenology-thompson-zahavi.pdf), a philosophical current: By using a technique called "Bracketing", one can focus the analysis on the living or feeling experience rather than on the final object as we're used to.

So now that I have tried to bring some context to my question, how can I understand *Being of or about* something?

Thank you !

Comment: I can't see that "of or" means anything, or add anything to the sentence.

Comment: @ColinFine: How about ***of*** = ***directly arising** from its intentional object*, as opposed to ***about*** being more a matter of some conscious experience being ***indirectly mediated*** by someone's attitudes / reactions to whatever they think the experience "means"? Such as, perhaps, the difference between the actual experience of having a row with your partner, and how you feel when you contemplate that experience? The second of which usually occurs somewhat *later*, but sometimes we can "externalise" our perspective *while simultaneously having the experience itself.*

Comment: ([intentional objects](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/1467-9329.00168) are hard to think about! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers So shall we say that "of" relates more to the real object, when "about" is rather related to the memory fingerprint ?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Indeed they are ! :)) Great examples, I will read the pdf you pointed at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Be of" in this context means directly a result of or stemming from some first-hand experience.  Put in other terms, it refers to something that is personally experienced by an individual.

> The memory I have **is of** being a child and being harshly punished.

"Be about" within this context refers to something that is remembered or related to, but not something that is necessarily part of one's first-hand experience and more anecdotal in origin. This is more of indirect much less personal memory that you are experiencing in that moment.

> I have a memory that **is about** watching television and learning that Elvis had died.

Comment: Thank you, could you think of an example (to make it even clearer) ?