# Difference between 'of'' and 'about'

Tags: prepositions

Is there any difference in nuance between the following two sentences?
What do you think of this new design?
What do you think about this new design?

Comment: This might be a better question for English Language Learners SE.  Are you learning English?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "think of" and "think about"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71003/difference-between-think-of-and-think-about)